# Which game modes in DotA2 allow repicking?

Tags: dota-2

I just had a game of *Random Draft* and wanted to repick Phantom Lancer after Earthshaker and Bloodseeker were picked against us. I know that in some game modes such as *All Random* you can repick.
I am not sure whether I just didn't find the repick option quick enough, or if it is disabled in *Random Draft*.

Now, I just checked the [Liquipedia](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/dota2/Game_Modes) and [Gamepedia](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Game_modes), neither has an article on repicking, nor lists whether repicking is possible for each mode in the Game Mode.

**Which game modes in DotA2 allow repicking?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, after creating a few lobbies against bots for science:

The repick button is located in the bottom left, above the map.

[image: repick button is located in the bottom left, above the map]

The following game modes **allow repicking**:

- All Pick
- Least Played
- All Random
- Single Draft (among the three drafted)

These game modes do **not allow repicking**:

- Random Draft
- Ability Draft

Couldn't test the captain modes, as bots don't pick captains. ;)

Edit: I would assume though that all Captain Modes don't allow repicking, as that would make no sense.

Comment: CM does not allow repicking. As soon as you choose your hero(s) the enemy's turn starts. Repicking in this scenario would destroy the purpose of the mode (counterpicking etc)

Comment: Obviously, in CM mode, a captain cannot repick/reban a hero.:)